Can't serve django App behind Apache + Nginx
I have a Django App that I'm trying to deploy on our dev server through a domain name.
Our dev server uses apache, while I use nginx to serve my app and static/media files.
If I deploy it locally on my computer (localhost:port) everything works perfectly. Once I try it on our dev server, I cannot connect to the websocket endpoint.
First of all I deploy my app with a docker-compose.yml consisting of an nginx, django app, redis and postgres services.
Below is my nginx conf file
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name localhost;
    charset utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /app/static/;
    }
    
    location /upload {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https; 
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }
}

And here is my apache conf
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName our.dev.server
        <Location />
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:89/
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:89/
            # Proxy WebSocket connections to your application
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
            RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
            RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*)$ ws://127.0.0.1:89/$1 [P,L]
        </Location>
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/our.dev.server/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/our.dev.server/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        RequestHeader add X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

When I try to connect to the websocket it seems that either apache or nginx does not upgrade the http request to ws...
